# how to convert bitmap image to CIELab image?

Tags: c#

> Hello to stackoverflow members! This
>   is my first post but I love reading
>   the questions and answers on this
>   forum!
>
> I'm using VS2008, CSharp, NET 3.5 and
>   Windows XP Pro latest patches on this
>   project.
>
> I am reading in a jpeg file to a
>   bitmap image using CSharp in the
>   following way:
>
> ```
> Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("background.jpg");
> Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
> ```
>
> I then write some text and logos on g
>   using various DrawString and DrawImage
>   commands. I then want to write this
>   bitmap to a tiff file using the
>   command:
>
> ```
> bmp.Save("final_artwork.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);
> ```
>
> I don't know what the TIFF tags in the
>   header of the final resultant TIFF
>   file will be when you do bmp.Save as
>   shown above?
>
> But what I want to produce is a TIFF
>   image file with PHOTOMETRIC CIELab,
>   BITSPERSAMPLE 8, SAMPLESPERPIXEL 3,
>   FILLORDER MSB2LSB, ORIENTATION
>   TOPLEFT, PLANARCONFIG CONTIG, and also
>   uncompressed and singlestrip.
>
> Im fairly certain, at least I have not
>   found anything about Microsoft API and
>   CIELab, I can not convert the bitmap
>   image to CIELab photometric and the
>   other requirements using anything from
>   the Microsoft API or .NET 3.5
>   environment - someone please correct
>   if I am wrong.
>
> I have used libtiff in a project in
>   the past but just to write a tiff file
>   where the tiff image in memory was
>   already in CIELab format and all the
>   other requirements as noted per above.
>   Im not certain libtiff can convert
>   from my CSharp bitmap image, which is
>   probably RGB photometric, to CIELab, 8
>   bps, and 3 spp?
>
> Maybe I can use OpenCVImage or Emgu CV
>   or something similiar?
>
> So the main question is what is going
>   to be the easiest way to get my final
>   bitmap image as outlined above into a
>   CIELab TIFF and also meeting the other
>   requirements per above?
>
> Thanks for any suggestions and code
>   fragments you can provide?
>
> Neal Davis

Comment: Can the TranslateBitmapBits function be used for what I want to do above?

Answer (score 1):

Try the imagemagick library, i'm sure there's a good C# wrapper for it, it supports pretty much every image file format known to mankind!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention my hobby-project library: [Colourful](https://github.com/tompazourek/Colourful)

It supports conversion from RGB to CIELab. And you have many options to set, like white points and RGB working spaces. It also does chromatic adaptation, so the resulting colors should be the best possible result obtained.

But you will have to convert your image pixel by pixel, for example using [LockBits](http://www.mfranc.com/programming/operacje-na-bitmapkach-net-1/) method, which is faster than `SetPixel`, `GetPixel`.